# Xamarin.Forms - StackLayout labels going outside device width

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Can set percentage widths for elements?

The problem ive got is the 2nd label pushes the button off screen, how can you force a label to only take up the space available. I've tried setting minimum width of the elements.

```cs
 new StackLayout
 {
     Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,                                    
     Spacing = 0,
     Children = {       
         new Label() { Text = "TITLE", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start},
         new Label() { Text = "fsdf dsfsd fsdfsdfs ewtrey vjdgyu jhy jgh tyjht rhyrt rgtu gtr ujtrey gt yu tgrt uh tyui y5r rtuyfgtj yrjhrytjtyjy jty t ruy ujh i rt", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap},                                        
         new Button() { Text = "wee", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand}                                      
     }
 },
```

Comment: have you tried MaxWidth on the StackLayout?

Comment: The problem I had was i didnt know the width of the device, nor how to get it at run time. Femil Shajin's answer has shown me how.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question

Comment: you should always use grid for that purpose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try Using OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height),

**Code In your Xamarin.Forms Page**

```
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);

        Metrics.Instance.Width=width;
        Metrics.Instance.Height=height;
    }
```

**Singleton Class to Save the width and Height and Check orientation change**

```
public class Metrics
    {

        private static Metrics _instance;

        protected SessionData ()
        {
        }

        public double Width{ get; set; } //Width

        public double Height{ get; set; } //Height
        }
```

**Creating Stacklayout**

```
   var StackchildSize = Metrics.Width/3; 
   new StackLayout
   {
   Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,                                    
   Spacing = 0,
   Children = {       
     new Label() { Text = "TITLE", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start
     WidthRequest=stackChildSize},
     new Label() { Text = "<Your Text>", WidthRequest=stackChildSize,},                                       
     new Button() { Text = "wee", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,
     WidthRequest=stackChildSize,}                                      
 }
```

},